# Why doesn't this map of covid-19 cases in california counties show San Francisco as having at least *some* cases?

Tags: data

Why doesn't this map of covid-19 cases in california counties show San Francisco as having at least *some* cases?

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "USCounties"];

calData = 
  Module[{s = {}}, 
   Do[If[data[[k]][[1]] == Interpreter["USState"]["California"], 
     s = Join[s, {data[[k]][[2]]}]], {k, 1, Length[data]}]; s];

usaCountyCases[s_, c_] := 
 First[data[Select[MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], #State] &]][
     Select[MatchQ[
        Interpreter["USCounty"][c <> " county, " <> s], #County] &]][
    All, #ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &] // Normal, 0]

caCountyCases[countycode_] := 
 usaCountyCases["Ca", calData[[countycode]][[2]][[1]]]

countiesValues = 
  Table[calData[[k]] -> caCountyCases[k] , {k, 1, Length[calData]}];

min = 0;

max = 100;

GeoRegionValuePlot[countiesValues, PlotRange -> {min, max, Automatic},
  ImageSize -> Full]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying the `data` in a complicated way. For San Francisco, you'll have `usaCountyCases["Ca", "SanFranciscoCounty"]`, and inside the code it becomes `Interpreter["USCounty"]["SanFranciscoCounty county, Ca"]`. The string is so invalid that the `Interpreter` fails to interprete:

> No US county interpretation found. Try again.

Actually, if the plot is what you only desire, here's all the code you need:

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "USCounties"];

countiesValues =
 data[Select[#State == Interpreter["USState"]["California"] &],
     {"County", "ConfirmedCases"}][
    All,
    {"ConfirmedCases" -> (#["LastValue"] &)}][
   All,
   Apply[Rule]] // Normal;

GeoRegionValuePlot[countiesValues, PlotRange -> 1000, 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

... where you get the correct figure `3400` for San Francisco.

Comment: Thanks! The code I was using was a lot slower.  How would I make the GeoRegionValuePlot have tooltips which gives (hopefully) both county name and covid-19 cases.  TIA

Comment: @VeritasLux You can refer to [`GeoLabels` option of `GeoRegionValuePlot`](https://wolfram.com/xid/0k75gqlc98r0y-5l9r1e). But this is another question and a new post is suggested.